# DATE_TRUNC with :: and without

Tags: sql

**The query only works when there is `:: DATE`.**

```
 -- Wrap the query you wrote in a CTE named reg_dates
    WITH reg_dates AS (
      SELECT
        user_id,
        MIN(order_date) AS reg_date
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY user_id)
    
    SELECT
      -- Count the unique user IDs by registration month
      DATE_TRUNC('month', reg_date) :: DATE AS delivr_month,
      COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS regs
    FROM reg_dates
    GROUP BY delivr_month
    ORDER BY delivr_month ASC;
```

**Why is that required? When I run the query below, without `:: DATE`, it does not work.**

```
-- Wrap the query you wrote in a CTE named reg_dates
WITH reg_dates AS (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    MIN(order_date) AS reg_date
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY user_id)

SELECT
  -- Count the unique user IDs by registration month
  DATE_TRUNC('month', reg_date) AS delivr_month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS regs
FROM reg_dates
GROUP BY delivr_month
ORDER BY delivr_month ASC;
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly likely your RDBMS is PostgreSQL, in your case the `::` converts a date type of date, further, `::` is  represented as `CAST(expression AS type)`.

Equally,

```
CAST (DATE_TRUNC('month', reg_date) AS DATE) AS delivr_month
```

Answer (score 0):

What does "does not work" mean? Note that `date_trunc` in PostgreSQL returns a `datetime`. So if you need a date for your query to work, this is why you need `::date`.